# Æ Ø Å do not work (updating div every 10 second)

Tags: html, character-encoding

When I update a div's content every 10 seconds, special characters like ÆØÅ become question marks. What is wrong? Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
   $('#chat').load('#chat');
}, 10000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds

</script>
<body>
<div id="chat">
<div class="melding">
        <form action="chat.php?login=<?php echo $bruker; ?>" method="post">
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td><input style="width: 420px;" type="text" name="melding"><input style="
border: 1px solid white;
    background: #333;
    color: white;"type="submit" name="send" value="Send"></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </form>
<div style="color: white;">
    <?php
    $print = "SELECT * FROM chat WHERE (fra='$user' AND til='$bruker') OR (fra='$bruker' AND til='$user') ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 100";

    $resultat = mysql_query($print);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultat)){ 
echo "<span class='red'>". nl2br(strip_tags($row['fra'])) .":</span> ". nl2br(strip_tags($row['melding'])) ."<br>";
}
?>
</div>
</div>
```

My code is saved in UTF-8 format

Comment: well your code is saved as utf8, is the webpage itself set to unicode encoding (for your browser)?

Comment: It's important to clarify if by questions marks you mean `?` or `�`. In the former case there is a deeper problem and in the latter case your data simply isn't utf-8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this meta tag to the page:

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

It tells the browser that the characters you provide are encoded in UTF-8.
Be sure that the other content of the page is also encoded in UTF-8.